# Ternary error detection and correction

Tags: .net, error-correction

For those of you familiar with forward error correction codes, I need a sample of a ternary (0-1-2 or even better - a generic base) messages encoder / decoder . That can efficiently restore ~20% damaged bits (trits).
I came across lots of binary snippets but none in other bases.

Can you please point out a good .NET implementation?

Lilian

Comment: Please See this First. [How-do-I-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [FEC is explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction).
I need a .NET code that implements a ternary FEC

Comment: What exactly is the motivation for using the field F3? As oppose to the binary, or even a binary extension field?

Comment: This is for (experimental) system that is capable of sending 3 different tones over a noisy channel.

Comment: I guess the F3 field is not very common. Thoughts anyone?